# Where to report Gitbook error (Problem loading page)

Tags: documentation

When I try to visit [CiviCRM's GitBook](http://gitbook.civicrm.org) I am forwarded to https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6 with the following error:

[image: Gitbook]

Who should I report this to?

Comment: Was working for me an hour ago - and still is. As in I do not get redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report infrastructure-related bugs on the "Infrastructure" project of JIRA (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/INFRA/).

I opened an issue for this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/INFRA-175

Answer (score 2):

If you experience this problem when trying to view the documentation it may be that your browser is either Chrome or Firefox and that you have previously visited the same page prior to 22 March 2016 (or for Firefox perhaps just visiting the main site https://civicrm.org could be enough).

The gitbook link now redirects to http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6 (the read the docs version). The read the docs version previously used https and the switch to http can cause problems. I am not an expert on this but I know it has something to do with HSTS. I think that Chrome and Firefox will redirect to https even if you specifically enter http if the sub-domain previously used https.

I was able to solve the problem with Chrome by deleting docs.civicrm.org from chrome://net-internals/#hsts (clearing caches or browser history did not work for me).

I have not yet managed to solve the problem with Firefox. Again clearing caches or browser history did not work for me.

Comment: I thought it was working last night when I checked but that was from my phone -- this morning the browser in my computer is doing the same thing. (FF)

Comment: Someone with .htaccess permissions could try this... http://svictor.net/tools/joomla,-html-co/205-make-firefox-chrome-forget-hsts-for-your-site

Comment: `curl -s --head https://civicrm.org | grep Strict` shows no `includeSubDomains` so this setting has been preserved from previous docs.civicrm.org visits. If this HSTS setting is affecting visitors to docs.civicrm.org still, it is possible to clear HSTS on subdomains via the parent domain with `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains`. A better solution is to use SSL on docs.civicrm.org OR to not use an HSTS'd hostname on a non-SSL provider.